# Synonym to 'legible' (but not just for text)

Tags: synonyms

I'm in correspondence with website designer. The site has an area where background and text are of similar colors, so the text is not legible on the background.

The designer understood my phrase "text is not legible on the background", but I wonder if there is more specific and natural English way to say that **something** (not only text) **is blending or mixing with background** so it hardly can be seen or distinguished.

Comment: hard to read, barely readable, unreadable, practically invisible...

Comment: In general, *legible* and a common synonym *readable* refer only to texts. So if you want a word that can have broader application, you have to go to something like *distinguishable* or one of its [synonyms](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english-thesaurus/distinguishable)

Comment: I'm talking rather about an antonym to 'distinguishable'. How would you say that colors of two objects are similar, so that when objects are overlaid they look as a whole?

Comment: The font color is too low-contrast, rendering the text unreadable.

Comment: Instead of indistinguishable, how about "barely distinguishable"? As in, "The text is barely distinguisable from the background," or, "The colors are so similar, they are barely distinguisable from each other."

Comment: Yes, I was considering this word but I think there must be more suitable alternative, maybe not so formal.

Comment: Sometimes it's better to use more words than to look for a more precise single word synonym.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time has passed I would use **'blur'** for this case. I think it is exactly what I wanted to say, but I would also agree that this choice is pretty subjective.

Answer (score 0):

**Since**, it's not just for the text on the background, I'd probably say...

> Maintain the contrast...

You may add whatever you want to say after those three dots. Maybe, between the background and elements, text, objects, content or the like.